# is there any connector available for NTFTP for file transfer in Spring integration channel?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am looking for a spring integration connector for NTFTP for file transfer?Any one has done similar configuration for this please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not; contributions to the framework are welcome.